# Trouble installing OpenCOBOL

Tags: mac

When I run `./configure`, I get this error:

```
configure: error: libdb is required
```

I signed up for an Oracle account (yak shaving), downloaded [Berkeley DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/downloads), untarred and unzipped, wrestled with the unhelpful README, successfully `configure`d, `make`d, and `make install`ed.  But the [OpenCOBOL](http://www.opencobol.org/) configure script still doesn't see the library.

Answer (score 1):

The configure script cannot find Berkeley DB; you have to tell it where libdb is.

```
$ ./configure CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.5.2/include/" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.5.2/lib/"
$ make
$ make install
```

Updated [README](https://github.com/mcandre/opencobol/blob/master/README.md)